# Move between tabs with slick carusels

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I have 3 similar tabs with slick carousels, but different content. When I move to another tab carousel becomes slim. Tab changes just by adding class `hidden(display:none)`. Tried bootstrap tabs, the same problem. [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km1Uw.png) changing tab, [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grhdF.png) changing tab.

Example
https://jsfiddle.net/vzqp5k3e/6/

Forgot to say. After slide changes carousel behave normal.

Comment: Tried setting min height property? Can you post a jsfiddle link where we can debug the issue?

Comment: @PavanJ yes, https://jsfiddle.net/vzqp5k3e/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to destroy the slick object then reinitialize it.

```js
  $('.my-carousel').slick('destroy');
  $('#myCarousel'+nbr).slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000});
```

eg. https://jsfiddle.net/9r63vkqa/

Comment: Thanks a lot, had some trouble with it.